# Printing .doc 2007 to a printer and a pdf writer simultaneously?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printer, printing

I routinely compose work-related memo's to clients in Microsoft Word 2007.  I file the paper copy and email a PDF of it to the client.

My current workflow is

```
 1. print->paper printer
 2. print->cutePDF writer->save dialog->browse->print (save).
```

My ideal workflow is

```
           |->paper printer
 1. print->|
           |->pdf
```

Is there a print driver or software add-in or native word function to do this?

Comment: You could accomplish this using a [VBA macro](http://wordprocessing.about.com/od/workingwithmacro1/l/blmacrointro.htm).  First record yourself going through the steps, and see what code it generates (post it back here).  We can go from there.  If you're opposed to VBA, then there's not much you can do aside from automating it with a utility like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)...

Comment: A macro is the way to go.

Comment: Yes the macro was simple and effective.  Thanks.  I posted the steps in an answer, but I'd like to continue to hear from anyone with more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Control Panel** > **Printers and Fax**. Then right click on one the printer listed there and choose **Properties**. Switch to the **Ports** tab. Next, add checkmark next to the printers you'd like to use simultaneously -- that'd be the hardware printer and the softw

Edit: As per this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457109.aspx#EDAA) on Microsoft Technet, Printer Pooling can only be done with printers of the same model. Sorry kevtrout, I think you cannot print to a hardware printer and PDF simultaneously -- at least not with Windows' built-in facilities. The only way to print to different printers simultaneously is by using an add-on program, either in form of script or compiled application like [MultiPrinter Port](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Other-Office-Tools/MultiPrinter-Port.shtml).

Comment: Printer spooling is enabled by default, and is **not** what @kevtrout is asking for.  He wants to know how to just go File -> Print and have it go to both printers.

Comment: I thought this would do it, once he has made those changes, if he prints to that printer the print job will go to the printers selected

Comment: @admintech Printer spooling allows the printer itself to begin printing *before* the entire job has reached it.  If you disabled spooling, you would have to wait for the printer to load the entire job *before* it started printing.  This is especially useful if you are queuing documents to be printed to a single printer (no wait times between jobs, they start instantly even while the printer is buffering).

Comment: @Larssend might have meant "printer pooling" which is the option available on the ports tab.  There's also a message that indicates that the document will print to the first free port checked.  This is preventing multiple ports to be used.  Any thoughts how to circumvent?

Comment: @kevtrout: Post edited.

Comment: You can't print to multiple ports. Not without a custom application, or a real print server.

Answer (score 0):

**With [@Breakthrough](https://superuser.com/users/6887/breakthrough)'s suggestion I recorded a macro that works well.**

1. Go to the developer tab
2. Select "Record macro"
3. Provide a name and in my case, choose a button to run it
4. Click Ok, add new macro to the quick access toolbar
5. I selected an icon by clicking "modify" under the QATB list
6. Click ok, perform the actions required to print to a hardware printer and pdf software
7. Click "stop recording".

Now the icon I selected is in the QATB and when clicked, prints to the two printers I defined.

Please continue to post any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You really are looking for [Ricoh Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info).

You can do this:

```
           |->paper printer
 1. print->|
           |->pdf
```

but also this:

```
           |->paper printer
 1. print->|
           |->pdf
           |->pdf2
           |->paper printer2
           |->email1
           |->fax2
```

or this:

```
           |->batch printers (printer1, printer2, ..., printer97)
 1. print->|
           |->pdf
           |->...
```

and this is only the basic stuff it does.
See some other basic things it does: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2

*(I'm affiliated with the product)*